# Вывод слов, в котроых содержатся определенные буквы

Tags: python

Всем здравствуйте.
Нужно вывести слова, в которых содержатся определенные буквы (минимум один раз).
У меня получается вывести слова в котрорых содержится только какая-то одна буква, а нужно, чтобы работало с несколькими буквами.
Подскажите, пожалуйста.

```
letter = "к л м"
text = "Клон Лом Море"
for word in text.split():
    if letter in word.lower():
        print(word)
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, пару примеров. Вы можете сделать это, нажав кнопку [edit]. Правильно ли я понимаю, что в Вашем примере не должно быть выведено ничего, так как букв `к`, `л`, `м` одновременно нет ни в одном слове? Или нужно вывести слово, если в нём есть хотя бы одна из перечисленных выше букв?

Comment: Нужно вывести те слова, в которых есть хотя-бы одна из этих букв.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться вложенным циклом, поочередно проверяя вхождение каждой буквы.

***Пример:***

```py
letters = 'клм'
text = 'Клон Лом Море'

for word in text.split():
    for letter in letters:
        if letter in word.lower():
            print(word)
            break
```

***stdout***

```py
Клон
Лом
Море
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.